# Sharing failed. The sharing operation failed due to an unexpected failure condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-sharing

We want to share a file with external user, using these steps:-

1. Access the document advance permission page
2. Stop permission inheritance
3. "Grant Permission" >> uncheck "Require sign-in"
4. click on Share >> but we got this error:-

[image]

any advice Thank

Comment: Is external sharing enabled for this SharePoint tenant and SharePoint site?

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes external sharing is enabledfor Anyone,, and if i check the "Require Sign-in" the process will work

Comment: @GaneshSanap seems the error is specifically when unchecking the checkbox